# Exactly when did Madara come back to life after his defeat by Hashirama?

Tags: naruto

I know that Madara used [Transcription Seal: Izanagi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Transcription_Seal:_Izanagi) to fake his death and came back to life after a while. What was the trigger for this jutsu (Izanagi)? If it was his death, immediately he would've come back to life after death and Hashirama would've noticed it.

It is mentioned that he had used this jutsu on his own right eye. How come a dead person's eye is a trigger for his own revival? As I understand, there won't be any movement/thought from a dead person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Izanagi is a technique which is able to **rewrite history**. You take an event that wasn't favorable to you and make it into nothing more than a dream.

He set up Izanagi beforehand to be trigger a few hours after his death. Even though he was already dead, the technique still activated (Much like Itachi sealed his own Amaterasu into Sasuke's eye, and it activated even though Itachi already died).

Once Izanagi was activated, Madara's death was cancelled.

Comment: Itachi's scenario was different than Madara's . In itachi's case, the trigger was alive(Sasuke's Sharingan). Also, It was an event based trigger. But in Madara's case, it was a timely trigger like a 'Time Bomb'. That too the trigger was already dead. Is that even allowed ?

Comment: Also @KaguyaOtsutsuki, apparently, it is :)

Comment: But it was said that in order to control the time freely of izanagi one must have Hashirama cells yes Madara did bite hashiramas arm but he still didn’t implant the cells into his body