# When did Uchiha Madara actually bite Hashirama Senju?

Tags: naruto

After reading [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13345/when-exactly-did-madara-came-alive-after-his-defeat-against-hashirama), I realized that the time Madara acquired Izanagi, was the same time he got the DNA of Senju Clan from Hashirama. However, after an extensive review on their fight (Episode 626), I can't see where and when Madara bit Hashirama. It said in the wiki that:

*"...To use Izanagi to its full potential, users must also have the genetic traits of the Senju, who are also descended from the Sage.."*

Now, the question is when and where did Madara bite Hashirama?
How come Madara activated Izanagi (I assume on its full potential) just right after he acquired the flesh/blood from Senju?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been keeping up with the anime (too many fillers...), so I don't know whether this manga chapter has been covered or not, or if you are even close to it. This was actually shown in one of the manga chapters quite recently.

If you don't mind spoilers, here are links to a few pages from Naruto Chapter 681:

[Madara bites Hashirama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v45X8.jpg)

[Madara uses Hashirama meat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iITKE.jpg)

According to [Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izanagi#Trivia):

> In the past, Uchiha clan members used this technique during an important battle that they had to win at all costs. However, they soon started to abuse the abilities granted by this technique and as such Izanami was created as a way to punish the abusers of Izanagi.

So, I am guessing that the Uchiha must have performed some experiments. Maybe as long as you have the both trait in body you can use Izanagi immediately, and Madara was aware of this. Since Madara clearly must have bit onto the meat, he must have swallowed some blood, thus having the Senju trait in his body. This is an assumption, though.

Comment: Wow. That was the episode I am looking for but I have a follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Izanagi has nothing to do with Senju powers. The requirement for Izanagi is that you must be ready to sacrifice one sharingan. If you have more than one, then you can cast it for as much as you have, which is the case with Danzo. The power that is awaken by having both Senju and Uchiha power is Rinnegan. Senju power however, can be used to extend the duration of Izanagi, which is once again, is the case with Danzo.

Now, to the main question, Uchiha Madara bite Senju Hashirama during their fight at the Valley of the End where it was believed Madara was killed by Hashirama. It was actually Madara's Izanagi. Later, when he was nearing his death, Madara awakens his Rinnegan. (Naruto Chapter 681)

Comment: Narutopedia states you **must** have the genetic traits of Sage of 6 Paths, or have both Indra's(Uchiha) and Ashura's(Senju) genes to use Izanagi. Also, Danzo, while having 10 Sharingan's embedded on his right arm, he also had Hashirama's DNA implanted into his arm, thus enabling the use of Izanagi.

Comment: Actually, you really don't need Senju's DNA to utilize Izanagi but you need those to fully/completely utilize Izanagi. On Madara's end, you can't use Izanagi for more than 10 secs delay. With that said, he *must* have Senjus' traits/DNA.

Comment: @NaraShikimaru what would happen if you tried to use Izanagi without Senju DNA and what would be the cost for it? Will it still rewrite reality? I didn't know about this bit, I must have skipped it.

Comment: @Hououin Kyouma It will still work, but the duration will be shorter than if you have Senju DNA. If you have Senju DNA, you can use it for a longer time, but as to how long, it depends on the degree of compatibility between your body and the Senju cells. The better, the longer you can use it. It was hinted during the fight between Danzo and Sasuke.

Comment: Oh, as for how Danzo requires Hashirama DNA to use Izanagi, please do remember that he is not an Uchiha, nor a Senju.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need senju cells for izanagi. Itachi used it on Kabuto. And he has had nothing to do with cell transplanting and whatnot.

Comment: Itachi used Izanami, not Izanagi, and the wording of this answer is at best low quality.